# Strange Pager behaviour in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a standart Page within my ListView control on the page, And the Pager is work, however in order to move to next list of items i required to click on pager link twice before it actually moves to next set of items.

The code for the pager is:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lv_LostCard" runat="server" DataKeyNames="request_id" EnableViewState="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
               <table width="550" border="1" class="table">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </table> 
                <asp:DataPager ID="lv_Books_Pager" runat="server" PageSize="10">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                        <asp:NumericPagerField />
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>               
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

and the Code behind is:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            getLostCardsList();
        }
    }

```
 protected void getLostCardsList()
    {
        using(LostCardsManagementDataContext LostCard = new LostCardsManagementDataContext())
        {
            var getLostCardsList = from lc in LostCard.lostcard_request_cards
                                   select lc;
            lv_LostCard.DataSource = getLostCardsList;
            lv_LostCard.DataBind();
        }
```

Can somebody tell me what happening and how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have problems with listview sincerely.

I found a solution related to your question which seems there is no other way to fix that.You need to call OnPreRender method to rebind your source to listview.

```
protected void listview_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getLostCardsList();//your method for binding
}
```

Be adviced, **PreRender events called before your page is rendered**.More clearly,if your page has a postback event will render again.That means you need to store your data into a server collection (i.e. Session).

Answer (score 1):

DataBind in the PagePropertiesChanged event.

```
private void listview_PagePropertiesChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listview.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding your listview in code? Make sure you are only doing that on non-postbacks.

Comment: Yes i do, in my code behind i have if (!Page.IsPostBack), it is really drives me crazy and i have no idea why it behaves that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have turned off the viewstate on your ListView. Try it with the viewstate back on.